# Switch statement on a user inputted variable without knowing it's max value

Tags: java

I know the question statement might not make sense but I didn't know how to work it. Let me show with an example:

If I have this code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, PORT_NUMBER);
for (int i = 0; i < someUpperLimit; i++) {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    switch(i) {
         case 1:
             out.write("2,3,4");
         case 2:
             out.write("1,3,4");
         case 3:
             out.write("1,2,4");
         case 4:
              out.write("1,2,3");
         ...
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the value for `someUpperLimit` is a user entered value form the command line and I don't know it's value when I am in the for loop. So in the switch statement I don't know how many cases I would have to write.

In each case statement I want to send over to the my server socket on the other end the values that are not in the case statement. So if the value in the case is `1` I want to send `2,3,4` over, etc. Is there another way to doing this since I have no clue how many case statements I would need in this case.

Comment: and which values do you need to send to server? from 1 to upperLimit?

Comment: @StinePike Yes if the case is `1` then I want to send `2 to someUpperLimit`. If the case is `2` then I want to sent `1, 3 - someUpperLimit` excluding the 2.

Comment: You can't use a `switch` statement if you don't know all the cases. Use a second `for` loop with an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java 8+, you could nest a pair of `IntStream`(s) like

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, someUpperLimit)
        .forEachOrdered(x -> out.write(IntStream.rangeClosed( //
                        1, someUpperLimit).filter(y -> x != y) //
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","))));
```

If you aren't using Java 8+, or you don't understand the above, then it's equivalent to something like the following

```
for (int x = 1; x <= someUpperLimit; x++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int y = 1; y <= someUpperLimit; y++) {
        if (y != x) {
            if (sb.length() != 0) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(y);
        }
    }
    out.write(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement in your case is redundant. You can simply create an ArrayList and fill it with values from 1 to the `someUpperLimit`. Then in your loop remove the `i`th element from list and write it to `out`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `switch case` statements at all. According to your requirement you can do the following.

1. Fill an ArrayList from 1 to someUpperLimit.
2. For each i from 1 to someUpperLimit .. send all the elements from the ArrayList except i.